# NavigationLink not pulling new view into correct location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a NavigationLink that is pulling a Form view on top of a list view. The thing I am experiencing is this "rubber band" effect that is happening when the view is pulled in. I can't really explain it with works so [here is a gif explaining it](https://giphy.com/gifs/QBRHGDdBPF4hCRDstI)

Here is a snippet of the navigation view

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(self.tables) { table in
            NavigationLink(destination: TableStatusView(table: table)) {
                tableCellView(tableNumber: table.number, clean: table.clean, inUse: table.inUse)
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And here is the view it's pulling in

```
struct TableStatusView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Table.getAllTables()) var tables: FetchedResults<Table>
    
    @State var table: Table
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Text("Table \(table.number)")
            }
            
            Section {
                Toggle(isOn: $table.inUse) {
                    Text("In Use")
                }
                
                Toggle (isOn: $table.clean) {
                    Text("Clean")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `@FetchRequest` works, but you might be blocking the main thread, causing the animations to jump. Try removing that code, or moving it into `.onAppear` to see if the issue persists or goes away.

Comment: The fetch request is for CoreData. Unfortunately it's not possible to move this as property wrappers are not yet available available on local properties. They must be put before the view, such as `@State` and `@ObservedObject`